# Can I force my iOS device to connect to 1 Wifi network over another

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

We have 2 wifi networks quite close to each other in our workplace, but I need to connect my iphone or ipad to 1 over the other out of preference.  It's fine for myself as I can simply change wifi networks, but if my boss's device connects to the wrong one (which connects to a seperate subnet) he want's it to just work?

Is there a way I can simply order them, or get it to pick one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how I managed to miss this before, but it appears they are simply joined in **alphabetical** order

1. mywifinetwork
2. mywifinwk2

1 Will always be picked over 2

If you are able to persuade you're IT staff to change the name (SSID) of the network then you can do this

1. mywifinetwork
2. A_mywifinetwork

or

1. mywifinetwork02
2. mywifinetwork01

Should make sure 2 is always connected in preference to 1 when both are available

I've tested this a bit, but i'll come back and update if it stops working. So Far So Good Though.

If you can't get the SSID's changed then there is a much more complex solution here http://nootrix.com/2012/01/prioritize-wifi-on-iphone/

Comment: holy cow holy cow holy cow THAT'S HOW IT DOES IT!

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the unwanted network, then go to "Settings -> WiFi", select that network and choose "Forget This Network". The device won't try to connect automatically to that network anymore, until you tell you to do so, choosing manually the WiFi network.

Also see [this link](http://www.cultofmac.com/143029/how-to-forget-a-wi-fi-network-on-your-ios-device-ios-tip/).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt solve my problem.  I still want to be able to connect to all networks, just 1 before 2 etc.  Naming as above and connecting in order seems to have solved the problem to a great extent.

Answer (score 0):

I exactly the same problems as you had, so I wrote an app to fix them. I have released "WiFi Priority" on the app store this week. You can simply create a configuration profile with it, which prevents the device from auto joining the specified network. However, you are still able to manually join this network by simply tapping on it in your network list.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-priority/id963277048?mt=8&uo=4&at=11ltdi

Let me know how you like it!

Comment: Pointless app! It doesn't do anything you can't do through your phones settings. 1. click settings 2. Click Wi-Fi
3. Find networks you wish to not auto join
4. Click on little blue circle with I in it
5. Click "Forget This Network" Could have just as well thrown .99$ out the window would have been just as helpful.. Wifi-priority... Incredibly misleading

Comment: Nice job making that app, but it appears from the reviews that it doesn't work in the way you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way to prioritize Wireless networks on iOS devices. The alphabetic order comment is just flat out wrong.