# How to prioritize WiFi networks on iPhone

Tags: network, iphone, settings

I can connect to multiple WiFi networks on my iPhone but the problem is that I cannot prioritize them. iPhone automatically connects to a specific network, which is slower in my case, and then I have to switch to the faster one from the network list.

How can I prioritize known WiFi networks on iPhone?

Comment: May be related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76547/can-i-force-my-ios-device-to-connect-to-1-wifi-network-over-another

Answer (score -2):

To ensure that your iPhone does not connect to the slower network, go to Settings > WiFi > tap on the blue arrow to the right of the slow network > tap on "Forget this Network"

Next, make sure you connect to the faster network. This way, your iPhone will connect to the fast network and not to the other each time the fast network is in range.

Comment: When I select "Forget this network", it deletes the password. When the fast network is out of range, I cannot connect to the slow network without selecting it from the list and entering the password. This does not answer my question.